# Word for "changing your mind" or the act of a mind being changed

Tags: synonyms

As in, the act of someone experiencing something that would change their view or choices about their chosen upcoming event.

Is there another way to say "changed my mind"?

Comment: Depends on how it's being cognized. _take a different path, try a different process, use a different program, throw the dice again,_ et extensive cetera.

Comment: One can *think better* of something:  I was going to go to the party, but then I thought better of it.

Comment: My previous opinion is no longer operational.

Comment: If you're a politician it's either "flip-flopping" or "refining your position".

Answer (score 4):

[Reconsider](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reconsider) may fit the context you are describing:

> - to consider (something) again, with a view to changing one's policy or course of action.

(AHD)

Comment: +1 Although, [technically](https://xkcd.com/1475/), One first *reconsiders* and then one either *changes one's mind, (or not)* based on that reconsideration.

Answer (score 0):

I refound **Metanoia** which is by far my favorite answer to this question

> **Metanoia** - [a profound... transformation conversion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/metanoia), [Change in one’s way of life resulting from penitence or spiritual conversion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/metanoia), [a change of mind, change in the inner man](http://biblehub.com/greek/3341.htm)

[In the New Testament **metanoia** (and its related verb, metanao) is the most commonly used word to express the idea of "repentance". the compound word... generally means "changing your mind" or "thinking differently" ultimately beginning with how we think and what we regard as truth](http://www.hebrew4christians.com/Holidays/Fall_Holidays/Elul/Metanoia/metanoia.html)

> **[Reassess](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/reassess)** - Consider or assess again, especially while paying attention to new or different factors
>
> **[Emend](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/emend)** - Make corrections and improvements to

re-evaluate could also work